# error: no matching function for call to Constructor with NULL as argument?

Tags: c++, constructor

I get the following error when I try to initialize a `Team` in `main()` doing:

```cpp
Team gt(NULL);
```

> error: no matching function for call to 'Team::Team(NULL)'

I'm unsure of how to go about this, as its a test case, so I can't change it.

I have other subclasses of `Team`, but I'm not sure how to go about actually initializing a `Team` with `NULL` as the parameter?

Here is my `Team` class:

```cpp
class Team
{
public:
  // Each team has a pointer to the next team to forward to
  // by default, a team is inactive
  Team();
  // can handle this?
  virtual bool CanHandle(const Ticket &t) const;
  // handle the ticket; if handled, return true; otherwise, return false
  virtual bool Handle(const Ticket &t);
  // Set the team to be active (f=true) or inactive (if f=false)
  void SetActive(bool f) {active = f;};
  // Is the team active?
  bool IsActive() const {return active;};
  
private:
  bool active = false;
  Team next_team;
};
```

**EDIT**: I forgot to include that I've tried having a constructor with `Team(Team *p)` but this leads to an "undefined reference to vtable" error. Additionally, its a class representing a chain of responsibility, so it will point to another `Team` object or NULL.

Comment: Your `Team` class has no constructors that take a parameter.  What are you hoping will be done with that `NULL` parameter?

Comment: You are getting ahead of yourself!  You mention that a line in `main()` is not compiling, but this code [already doesn't compile](https://www.godbolt.org/z/KcYvas) -- regardless of main.

Comment: You can't have a class containing itself. That would lead to an infinite size. Because every team object will have a next_team having a team ... c++ does not have a hidden pointer that can be null like some other languages do.

Comment: "*this leads to an "undefined reference to vtable" error*" - we need to see a [mcve] demonstrating that

Comment: I am voting to close the issue: The topic is on calling a constructor with null as argument, but the accepted answer is how to implement a linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say `Team` represents a NULL-terminated chain of `Team` objects, you need a linked-list of `Team*` pointers, where the last pointer in the chain is NULL.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
class Team
{
public:
  // Each team has a pointer to the next team to forward to
  // by default, a team is inactive
  Team() = default;
  Team(Team *t) : next_team(t) {}
  ...
  
private:
  ...
  Team *next_team = nullptr;
};
```

Now `Team gt(NULL);` will work, as will `Team gt(nullptr);` and even `Team gt;`

Comment: I would actually suggest that you remove the default constructor and make the default argument `nullptr` to support default construction: `Team(Team *t = nullptr) : next_team(t) {}` The extra constructor can become a maintenance issue if the constructor needs more initialization etc.

Comment: @CJCombrink I was going to do that originally, but I went with a `default`'ed constructor instead so that the `Team *next_team = nullptr;` initialization could be used as a complement to the `bool active = false;` initialization.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to default initialize an object is to just `Type obj;`. In your case, that would look like `Team gt;`. That calls your default constructor.

If you actually need to initialize a `Team` with a pointer, you need to write a constructor that can take a pointer, and then use `nullptr` and forget that `NULL` was ever a thing.

Your `Team` should also be **just** a `Team`. I see you trying to make it a `Team` *and* a list. That's a horrible idea.